# Does Magical Ambush affect Area of Effect spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *Rogue* archetype *Arcane Trickster* gains the feature **Magical Ambush** at level 9, which says

> if you are hidden from a creature when you **cast** a spell **on it**, the
>   creature has disadvantage on any saving throw it makes against the
>   spell this turn.

Spellcasting > Targets explains:

> A typical spell requires you to **pick** one or more targets to be
>   **affected** by the spell’s magic. A spell’s description tells you whether
>   the spell **targets** *creatures*, Objects, or a *point of origin for an area
>   of effect*

The Area of Effect section adds:

> Spells such as Burning Hands and Cone of Cold cover an area, allowing
>   them to **affect** multiple creatures at once.

These wordings don't make it clear to me whether creatures affected by Area of Effect spells are also considered as having these casted *upon* them, and as a result the following question emerges:

**Does Magical Ambush affect AoE spells?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Magical Ambush works on any spells that force a saving throw (including AOE)

[Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/893249557668085760) has clarified this directly:

> Q*: Does Magical Ambush impose disadvantage on AoE/line spells? Or is
> it only spells that target creatures?
>
> A: Magical Ambush works with any spell that forces a creature to make a saving throw.

*Question was paraphrased for clarity

Which makes sense given [he has clarified](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/897549515984654338) the topic of AOE targeting more generally:

> A typical area of effect has more than one target: the effect's point of origin and one or more creatures/objects.

Given these two rulings, is reasonable to read "when you cast a spell on it" to actually be saying "when you target a creature with a spell" or "when you affect a creature with a spell".

Comment: Awesome, this is the kind of ruling I was failing to find. Thanks for the definitive answer!

Answer (score 5):

### Spells with Saves

You've quoted the entire text of **Magical Ambush**:

> Starting at 9th level, if you are [hidden](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Hide) from a creature when you cast a spell on it, the creature has disadvantage on any saving throw it makes against the spell this turn.

At multiple times, the designers of 5E have indicated that the game is meant to be parsed as normal language whenever possible.<sup>1</sup> In other words, logic says if a spell affects a creature, then that spell was cast on that creature. Conversely, logic says if the spell wasn't cast on the creature, then they couldn't be affected by it. The fact that an area of effect is aimed at a point for targeting purposes, doesn't mean the spell is cast on that point alone.

It's pretty cut and dry - if the caster is hidden when the spell is cast, the target has disadvantage on the save. There's no more complexity to it. The type of spell doesn't matter, other than needing to be a spell that requires a save.

### Spells with Attack Rolls

As an aside, if the caster is [hidden](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Hide) and therefore [unseen](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#UnseenAttackersandTargets), he gets advantage on a spell attack roll, too.

<sup>1</sup><sub>As @Slagmoth indicates in the comments, there is a DragonTalk podcast from [Jan 19, 2017](http://media.wizards.com/2017/podcasts/dnd/DnDPodcast_01_19_2017.mp3) where this is detailed by Jeremy Crawford, specifically addressing spellcasting.</sub>

Comment: Is there any source for this? My understanding is that is principally possible that these spells are not considered cast on a creature but instead on an area with effect on creatures instead.

Comment: @hyperfekt That's an entirely different question from the one you asked.

Comment: Well, its answer is a necessary prerequisite to answer the question I asked in the absence of any other rules.

Comment: @hyperfekt That's not how things work here. You have to explicitly ask the question you want answered. You could certainly include your confusion on that fact as part of the explanation for why you're asking this question.

Comment: Thanks, done. I also added some citation for the source of my confusion, that should make it easier to answer my question.

Comment: @hyperfekt Check out the Jan 19, 2017 Podcast for DragonTalk on the Wizards site. Crawford talks a lot about targeting and what it actually means. In short, yes, creatures within an area effect are considered targets by definition.

Comment: Thanks, gonna give it a listen! If you don't mind I'm going to formulate an answer when I find the relevant statement.

Comment: @hyperfekt no worries... I would type one out but I am at work and don't have access to a lot of things from here. It goes into the soft usage of the word from English so it may not have the hard answer you want. Comes down to a ruling at your table in all honesty. I don't think it breaks anything nor do I think this interaction was unintended. They have used poor choices in wording for a lot of things in this edition.

Comment: @hyperfekt: here is a [direct link](http://media.wizards.com/2017/podcasts/dnd/DnDPodcast_01_19_2017.mp3) to the Jan 19, 2017 Podcast of DragonTalk where they talk about targeting.

Answer (score -4):

No, it does not affect the saves from area-of-effect spells.  An AoE spell is cast on an area, not on a creature, so the "when you cast a spell *on it*" part is what determines that the Magical Ambush does not apply to this situation.

Magical Ambush could potentially apply to multiple targets (check with your DM, he/she may differ), so I would say that if, for example, the Rogue casts *Hold Person* using a higher level spell slot to cast it on more than one person, that still counts as being cast "on it", and the disadvantage would apply.  Indeed, if the Rogue was hidden from some of the targets and not others, the disadvantage on the save would apply to each target he was hidden from, and not to any targets he was not hidden from.

But all of that is because in this second case, the spell is being cast *on the creature(s)*, while in the first case the spell is being cast *on a place* and happens to affect anyone within the area.

Comment: This is pretty strongly contradicted by the extensive discussion from the Sage Advice segment in the official DragonTalk podcast from January 19th of last year.  Jeremy Crawford goes into a great deal of detail (mostly in reference to Twin Spell, but it applies here) to say that the "targets" of a spell include anyone that is affected in any way by the spell.  When you cast Greenflame Blade and hit one guy with your sword and a blast of flame does automatic damage to a second guy, the spell targets two creatures, and everyone in a fireball is a target of the fireball.

Comment: But being "the target" is not the same as having the spell "cast on you".  And this is a good example of the distinction.  Is the spell magic affecting creatures, objects, or area?

Comment: @PhilBoncer I understand what you are saying but I really think that in some instances we read way too much into how things are worded. Besides this does not explicitly indicate it has to be a single target. If something affected multiple creatures like an up-casted Hold Person you can easily say that you cast the spell on *it*, *it* and *it*.

Comment: But "casting a spell on *it*" is a valid subset of "casting a spell on *it, it, and it*".  Whereas "casting a spell on *it*" is *not* a valid subset of "casting a spell on a *place* near *it*".

Comment: The thing here is that I am NOT reading things into things, or relying on picky wording. I'm basing my position on how magic is consistently stated to work. Spells are cast on creatures, objects, or locations, and it does matter which for a wide variety of reasons. The Rogue's Magical Ambush is pretty clearly about spells cast on creatures, whereas any area of effect spell is, by definition, cast on an area. That's a difference with regard to magic, and one that makes a distinction here.